# Dangerous value - Request.Form

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor

I am developing an application in ASP.NET 2.0, and in one page i am using a FCKEditor.

In some cases, when i try to save the content of the page i get an exception saying that a potentially dangerous value was detected Request.From from the client

> (FCKeditor1=" < fck:meta content="t...").

I couldn't detect so far in which specific cases (btw, how can this occur only on some saves?) this occurs but i googled a bit and tried to disable the validation for this page by adding validateRequest="false" to my editor page. 
This apparently solves the exception but raises another question.
With this on my page, the button that contains the saving code fails to cause a postback. I have a breakpoint on the first line of my button code on codebehind and it is not even fired.

So that you understand the structure of my page and as i said, i have the editor on my page and a button that on click executes code to retrieve the value from the editor and saving it.

EDIT:

```
<FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor HtmlEncodeOutput=true ID="FCKeditor1" runat="server" Height="700px" Width="800px" BasePath=""></FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor >
FCKeditor1.BasePath = EditorPath
FCKeditor1.Value = Line
```

This is basically what i am doing on the loading of the page. Setting the path and filling the value of the editor. On save, i do the opposite, retrieving the value and processing the string. This string (as seen by a breakpoint in one of the times the exception is not thrown) is something like:

```
<fck:meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><fck:meta content="text/css" http-equiv="Content-Style-Type"><fck:meta name="generator" content="Aspose.Words for .NET 9.6.0.0">
```

and more html ahead.

This is by far an annoying problem and any sugestion or enlightenment would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what's a typical value of the `Line` variable in your code example?

Comment: <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" /><meta name="generator" content="Aspose.Words for .NET 9.6.0.0" /><title></title></head><body><div><p .... and so on. It's basically a .doc document converted to html using Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

The error about a potentially dangerous value being submitted is usually triggered when a form post value contains angle brackets.

This is the case here as it looks like you're using the FCKeditor to edit HTML so you'll need the `validateRequest="false"` as you've already done.

As for the form not posting at all, this points to either:

- the markup is being corrupted somehow; examine the final markup in your browser with the View Source option, paying particular attention to opening and closing single `'` and double-quotes `"`
- if you're using IE6 or IE7 and a `<button />` element to submit the form, it needs the property `type="submit"`  (that one caught me out last week)

Comment: That makes some sense. How can i change that?

Comment: @seth - I haven't used `fckeditor`, so if can you add a few more complete lines of code in your example I might be able to work it out

Comment: I can try to do that, but it seems to me that this is actually the value of the fckeditor. If i stop the execution in one of the cases in which the exception is not thrown and inspect the value of the editor it is actually similar to this.

Comment: @seth - what does a View Source of the page with the editor in it look like?  Can you update your question with a complete line of markup?

Comment: I edited the original post. Was this what you were expecting?

Comment: @seth - yes that helps, could you expand on the `<fck:meta content="t...` bit please, as you did with the Page Load code?

Comment: @Should the value of HtmlEncodeOutput be in quotes too?
Yes, it should. However it didn't make any changes regarding the problem.

Yes, i will do that.